# Copying variable contents to clipboard while debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm debugging in Visual Studio Code and I have a JSON object that I would like to copy as text to the clipboard.

Is this possible inside of Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 39):

I found two ways to do that, both of which are a bit hacky (in my eyes).

#### Use console.log

I think there will be a limit to the size of the string that this can output, but it was satisfactory for my requirements.

1. In the debug console, write `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject))`
2. Copy the resulting output from the debug console. That can be a bit tedious for long strings, but a combination of mouse and keyboard (ctrl-shift-end) worked ok for me.

#### Use a watch (limited to 10'000 characters)

This method only works up to a limited size of the resulting json string (it looks like 10'000 characters).

1. Set a breakpoint in a reasonable location where your variable is in scope and start your app.
2. Go to the debug view, add a watch for a temporary variable, e.g. `tmpJson`
3. Get your breakpoint to hit.
4. In the debug console, write `var tmpJson = JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject)`
5. This will now have populated the watched variable `tmpJson` with the string representation of your json object
6. In the debug view, right click on the watched variable, click copy.

If the string is too long, it cuts it off with a message like the following:
`...,"typeName":"rouParallel","toolAssembly":{"id":"ASKA800201","description":"CeonoglodaloD50R6z5","c... (length: 80365)"`

But it would work for smaller objects. Maybe this helps some people.
It would be great to have this properly built-in with vscode.

Comment: for the first option if the text is longer than the viewable part of the console it gets cut off. And you've mentioned similar limitations in your second option. I almost want to write an extension but I have a feeling by the time I get around to it it will be fixed.

Comment: Wow. I swear I managed to copy a long range of text using the first approach when I fiddled around with it. But now I cannot do it again :-/
It looks like this might be addressed in the March iteration plan:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21923

Comment: How about in Python? ... merely the object memory address. v1.33

Comment: This doesn't work properly if the object in question implements their own `toJSON()` method that skips properties.  What you get on the console is not necessarily the same as what you get in the debugger.

Comment: Similar effect with PHP would be to issue `json_encode($variable)` in Debug Console. But then you'd need a JSON formatter though.

Answer (score 15):

I have an **easy workaround** to copy anything you want:

1. In the debug console, write `JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject)`
2. Copy the string without the double quotes `"` around the string
3. Open a browser, such as Chrome, open the inspecting tool, go on the console and write:

   `copy(JSON.parse("PASTE_THE_STRING_HERE"));`
4. The object is now copy on your keyboard !

Comment: command copy also works for me in the VS Code debugger which is attached to NodeJS Server

Answer (score 12):

There is an open issue regarding this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/624

Workaround :

1. Go to the VARIABLES panel and right click to show contextual menu on a variable
2. select Set Value
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

(tested on Java, not JavaScript)

Comment: the contextual menu includes an option to Copy Value that at least works for Python (v. 1.40.2)

Comment: Copy Value (python) does not work for me if the array has more than 14 characters. All but the 1st 14 get truncated and I just see ... at the end. Did you manage to get more that that?

Comment: In JavaScript, after copying the value, create a new file with the .json extension and paste into that file. The JSON will be formatted, but lacking quotes around the keys. This can be fixed (usually) by selecting the entire file and using the "Format Selection" command (Cmd-P Format Selection).

Comment: The Set Value workaround doesn't work for Python

Comment: There is no "set/edit value". Only "copy value"

Answer (score 10):

**Note**: this solution seems to work for *longer* values but not *very long* values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787648/99717) suggests a 10,000 char limit and uses `JSON.stringify(myvar)` instead of just `str()`. On char limit, see also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423774/copying-variable-contents-to-clipboard-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-code/69802136#comment125513299_69802136) below.

Tested in python debugger

- Add the variable to Watch, but converted to string

  `str(myvar)`
- Right-click on the *value* of the watch, and select `Copy Value`
- Now you should get the full value (but not for *very long* values. See note above).

(var name blurred out):

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for really long values, i.e. tf.Tensors

Comment: same issue here. long API value isn't coping all ... copy value is missing alot of data .

Comment: Good workaround that worked for me on a Python list of ~50 values.

Answer (score 5):

If you are **debugging Python**:

**In the DEBUG CONSOLE** type, for example:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(json.dumps(outDetailsDict))

OUTPUT IS LIKE
{"": {"stn_ix": 43, "stn_name": "Historic Folsom Station (WB)", "name": "", },
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in debug mode, you can copy any variable by writing copy() in the debug terminal.

This works with nested objects and also removes truncation and copies the complete value.

Tip: you can right click a variable, and click `Copy as Expression` and then paste that in the copy-function.

Comment: +1 for using the debug terminal, for me I just use `str(long_object_here)` and this makes sure the truncation is removed

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I found to do that on Visual Studio Code was

1. Adding a breakpoint where is located the object to copy
2. Right click on object and choose "Add to Watch"
3. From Watch sidebar, choose option "Copy Value" and it's all!

Comment: When this is an array on an object - this will not work

Comment: it just says "[object Object]"

Comment: partial value ending with ...

Answer (score 0):

While the question presumably deals with JavaScript (JSON) based technologies, many people have posted Python-related posts in this thread. So I'll post a more specific answer for Python, although the reasoning can be extended with some tweaks to JavaScript-based technologies.

**Helper strategies for debugging with VSCode**

Copying variable FULL VALUE (not truncated) to clipboard while debugging even for very long values and other additional strategies.

**1 APPROACH:** Access the "Run and Debug" screen and look for the "WATCH" area and double click inside it. Add something like `str(<MY_VAR>)` which should be the variable you want to find the value of during the debug process;

**2 APPROACH:** Access the "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab and in the footer (symbol ">") copy and paste the code below or another one of your choice...

```
def print_py_obj(py_obj, print_id="print_py_obj"):
    """Prints a Python object with its string, type, dir, dict, etc...

    Args:
        py_obj (Any): Any Python object;
        print_id (Optional[str]): Some identifier.
    """

    print(" " + str(print_id) + \
        " DEBUG >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(" 0 STR >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(str(py_obj))
    print(" 0 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    print(" 1 TYPE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(type(py_obj))
    print(" 1 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    print(" 2 DIR >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(str(dir(py_obj)))
    print(" 2 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    print(" 3 DICT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    try:
        print(vars(py_obj))
    except Exception:
        pass
    print(" 3 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    print(" " + str(print_id) + \
        " DEBUG <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")

print_py_obj(profit, "<MY_VAR_OPTIONAL_IDENTIFIER>")
```

**NOTE:** We may have a 10,000 character limitation for both approaches.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Yup ! That's very much possible
Select breakpoint near your json variable.Debug.
[screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDrIo.png) . Right click on json body and copy value.That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the copy value doesn't work, and this is my first time trying to do it in VS Code.

I was working on a big file where I had to save the Id's for Products and some other references of these products, and I could not find a way to save the current state of it. I made a really ugly but working solution for C#.

This is the dictionary variable I was trying to save data from:

```
var forRemoval = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Pasting this into the debug console and then just copy/paste the results somewhere else

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", forRemoval.Select(c => $"{c.Key}: {string.Join(", ", c.Value.ToList())}").ToList()));
```

It won't work if you do not add ToList() at the end.
You can also save the output to a file into the project's root folder.

```
File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "res.txt"), string.Join("\n", forRemoval.Select(c => $"{c.Key}: {string.Join(", ", c.Value.ToList())}").ToList()));
```

This returns a file with the following structure:

> ProductKey: ProductValue1, ProductValue2, ProductValue3
> ProductKey2: ProductValue5, ProductValue2